# How to separate combining characters in vim or a terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, vim, unicode

Is there a way, in `vim` or a terminal emulator like `xterm`, to "separate" combining characters? For example, with characters "ก" and "ุ", instead of combining to "กุ", just displaying "ก ุ". I.e. is there a way to treat unicode combining characters like normal characters?

Comment: If you can come up with a regexp that identifies combining characters (which itself is already not trivial to do), you could insert a whitespace character in between, so that the following combining character "combine" with the whitespace instead of the preceding character.